# Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant - Public Client

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, flask-oauthlib

I am trying to implement Oauth2 for a website using Python oauthlib. I have decided that I would like to use the grant type 'ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant', this is because the website and the API are my own and will not be open to third parties.

In 'resource_owner_password_credentials.py' why is 'client_authentication_required' hardcoded to return 'True'?

Do I need to authenticate my client (website)? From my understanding this would be a 'public' and not a confidential client.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the author of oauthlib interpreted the spec this way. The section on the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) says:

> (B)  The client requests an access token from the authorization
> server's token endpoint by including the credentials received
> from the resource owner.  When making the request, the client
> authenticates with the authorization server.

Note that it *suggests* that the client authenticates but it does not use the MUST keyword in that last sentence. Just below that there's slightly more elaborate text (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2) saying:

> If the client type is confidential or the client was issued client
> credentials (or assigned other authentication requirements), the
> client MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described
> in Section 3.2.1.

Note the "If the client is confidential", this time implying that public clients may use this grant type too, which makes sense.

So I believe this is due to a too strict interpretation of the wording in the specs.